# Make dynamically created DIVs droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am creating a dynamic form, where users can drag and drop fields. as part of the fields I have a section panel, which is also dynamically created. The idea of the section is to group fields. My problem is I am unable to drop elements on sections. Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
 <div class="row" id="droppable"></div
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $(".btn-call-type-div").draggable({
    cancel: false,
    refreshPositions: true,
    revert: true
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dragged_element = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
      var html = "";
      switch (dragged_element) {
        case 'section':

          html = '<div class="panel panel-flat">' +
            '<div class="panel-heading">' +
            '<h6 class="panel-title"><input type="text" placeholder="Section title", class="form-control" name="section[]" required></h6>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="panel-body">' +
            '<p class="panel-section">Drag section fields here</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
          break;
      }
      $("#section-paragraph").append(html);

    }
  });

  $(".panel-body").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dragged_element = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
      alert(dragged_element);
      var html = "";
      switch (dragged_element) {
        case 'select':
          //do something here when a select is dropped
          break;
        case 'checkbox':
          //do something here when a checkbox is dropped
          break;
        case 'textarea':
          //do something here when a textarea is dropped
          break;
        case 'text':
          //do something here when a text is dropped
          break;
      }
      $(this).find("p").append(html);
      $(this).css("height", "100%");
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of the above (including css and your complete html) would be useful.

Comment: Your code isn't doing anything with the dragged item. In the `.panel-body` `droppable` event, you're appending an empty string to a `p` contained within it. You need to replace html with `$(ui.draggable)`